# MS Access: How can I make this textbox automatically fill in a value based on a query?

Tags: forms, ms-access, autofill

I have 5 textboxes on a form.

1. job (text)
2. suffix (integer)
3. production date (date)
4. shift (text)
5. start time (time)

The user fills out these boxes and then submits the form to write to a table. The user does this multiple times per shift using the same information.

**The problem:** Sometimes the user forgets to fill out the 5th textbox, so I want to simply check their previously submitted values in the table and fill in the textbox with the max start time.

**What I tried:** I made a query to take the first 4 textboxes as critera and then return the max start time. The query works, but I can't get it to show up by default on the form. I used the default value property to point to the correct value in the query, but nothing shows up.

**The goal:** The 5 textboxes should be blank at first (which they are, currently). After the user fills out the first 4 textboxes, the 5th box should populate with the max start time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add AfterUpdate code for 4 fields, which should check value of all 4 first fields and if they are not empty, fill 5th textbox using DLookup from your query.

For instance you can call the function like this from all AfterUpdate events:

```
Private Function CheckData()
If Nz(Me.job, "") <> "" And Nz(Me.suffix, "") <> "" _
    And Nz(Me.[production date], "") <> "" And Nz(Me.Shift, "") <> "" Then

    Me.[start time] = DLookup("start time", "MyQuery", "job='" & Me.job & _
        "' and suffix=" & Me.suffix & " and [production date]=#" & _
        Format(Me.[production date], "yyyy/mm/dd") & "# and Shift='" & Me.Shift & "'")

End If
End Function
```